# Testing Security Settings for Server to Server Integration

Tags: security, website-integration, ssl

I am trying to access a web service built by a client that is hosted on their internal servers. They have exposed access to the public internet, but have restricted access to Salesforce's IP range. When I am trying to access their web service, I get an error suggesting the IP restrictions aren't set up right. But I am not sure what is the best way to troubleshoot this. If it was my local machine having problems, I would do simple tests via command line etc., but obviously I don't have those tools available from the Dev Console.

What have other folks used in the past to troubleshoot connectivity issues to a server when it is restricted to SFDC IP ranges?

EDIT:
At this point, I get this error in the SFDC Logs:

```
Access control configuration prevents your request from being allowed at this time.  Please contact your service provider if you feel this is incorrect.
```

I 'think' that is their proxy throwing an error, but I am trying to provide more detail to the client's team to help them fix the issue...

Comment: If you could be more specific we might have better answers; I've given my thoughts on generic troubleshooting, though.

Comment: The answer lies in the symptoms. Do you get a timeout? A connection refused? A "not allowed" error? Have you checked Remote Access settings? Are you crossing protocols (HTTPS->HTTP)? Did you configure salesforce.com to allow that, if so? What response are you getting from the server, if any? Given the limited number of issues that could occur, surely it couldn't be hard to diagnose. Also, you can use the JavaScript proxy to diagnose the problem via a web browser; Chrome's console is great for this.

Comment: See edit above - this isn't something they have much experience doing (exposing Web Services outside their firewall) so trying to move it along....

Answer (score 1):

This depends on the error; for a web service, I would make sure to log or output my callouts, including URL, headers, body, HTTP response code, and HTTP response body. This would allow me to see what I'm sending out and exactly what I'm receiving. I would also run the same callouts locally, just to ensure that my local machine is being properly denied and to compare error messages.

Anything more in-depth might require Salesforce support and their network engineers.